# How to remove a reference from sources in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word, bibliography

I have cited some sources in word by mistake, and I want to completely remove them from sources but it is not possible.
I've completely removed references from my document text
but the delete button is not active in source manager:
[image]

I need help to correct my references list.
how can I remove wrong sources? If I don't remove them, when I update bibliography table, they appear again like this:
[image]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments to the original version of this Answer it seems that this problem most likely occurs when the references are still in your document but have been hidden in one way or another.

It may be that the reference is still in your document but its text has been marked as Hidden (thanks to @imsteffan for that one). If you use the Show/Hide text button to reveal Hidden text, you may be able to see the reference.

Another way the reference might be hidden is if you are using Track Changes and you have a View Set (in Review->Tracking) that is not showing deletions and so on. In that case when you delete a Citation, it will still be in your document and will still appear in the Bibliography, until you Accept the changes.

Then, you should be able to select and delete the sources in the Source Manager.

Comment: Thank you @jonsson, yes track changes in on, I will try it after changes being accepted.

Comment: Turning off track changes worked!

Comment: @jonsson with such a good insight to share, I'm glad you couldn't make it a comment since I had a very similar problem (hidden text instead of track changes)